# How can I proceed firing events after using stopImmediatePropagation() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using css classes for firing events/functions.

```
<button class="func_check_data func_proceed">
```

The button calls different functions on the click event.

`func_check_data()` checks valid data and saves it on success.

So when function `func_check_data()` throws an error, `func_proceed()` shouldn't be fired.

By using `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` in `func_check_data` I get this working.

But, when `func_check_data` doesn't throw an error, `func_proceed` is fired, before `func_check_data` has saved the data successfully via ajax.

So is there any function which can be used to delay following events until the first one is finished?

Comment: This is what callbacks and promises do. Have a look into them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You'll want to have a single event handler that does this coordination, rather than multiple uncoordinated event handlers.

For instance:

- `.func_check_data` that aren't also `.func_proceed` elements can call the check data function handler.
- Similarly, `.func_proceed` that aren't also `.func_check_data` elements can call the proceed function handler.
- `.func_check_data.func_proceed` elements (e.g., ones that are both) would use a third handler that does the data check and ajax save, then when the ajax save is complete, does the proceed part.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to handle this kind of chaining logic is either:

- a `switch` or a block of `if/else`'s that routes the flow from one function to the other by manually calling the other function, or
- an ajax `request`/`response`, where the response runs the follow-up function

e.g.

```js
function follow_up(data) { /* do stuff */ }
function cancel(data) { /* undo stuff */ }
function clickHandler(e) {
  let url = 'foo';
  let data = {bar: 'baz'};
  $.ajax({
    url: url, data: data, method: 'POST',
    success: follow_up,  // see funcs above
    error: cancel,       // see funcs above
  });
}
```

Also, be aware you can manually trigger specific events with `$.trigger('eventName')`.